# Who consumes the queue on hornetQ

Tags: jms, hornetq

I have many applications (about 60) whom consumes messages on hornetQ queues.

Normally, each application consumes its own queue but I have some messages on a specific queue whom are consume by an unkown application.

For exemple, normally the application A consume the queueA but for a weird reason, some messages are not consume by this application (I log every entry in Jms listener) and I don't know who consumes those messages.

Is it possible to check on hornetQ what application consumes a message ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/intercepting-operations.html) to monitor at the server side which clients connect to the topic in question. Basically, you just write a class implementing the `Interceptor` interface. In the `intercept` method, you check for the packet type and log the client id. HornetQ provides a [simple example](https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/blob/master/examples/jms/interceptor/src/main/java/org/hornetq/jms/example/SimpleInterceptor.java).